# SQL - exclude values in column A unless column b unless column

Tags: sql

I want to only show rows where A is not in a list or B is not in a list or C has any non null value. I have tried writing similar to below but I'm clearly doing something wrong

```
SELECT
    A.date,
    A.1,
    B.1,
    C.1
FROM A JOIN B JOIN C  
WHERE
    A.date ='2020-08-23' 
    AND (
        A.1 NOT IN ('potato', 'tomato')
        OR B.1 NOT IN ('salad', 'soup')
        OR c.1 IS NOT NULL
    )
```

Comment: Maybe you actually want ANDed conditions instead of OR. Boolean logic is not always a direct translation from spoken language.

Comment: You are missing the ON clauses of the joins.

Comment: Add sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

> Use Inner join between A,B and C on date instead of Full join. And
> also use AND instead of OR.

```
SELECT
A.date,
A.1,
B.1,
C.1
FROM A Inner JOIN B ON A.Date=B.Date 
INNER JOIN C ON B.Date=C.Date
WHERE
A.date ='2020-08-23' 
AND(
A.1 NOT IN ('potato','tomato')
AND
B.1 NOT IN ('salad','soup')
AND
c.1 IS NOT NULL
)
```